# Using PyCharm with a monorepo containing multiple projects

Tags: pycharm, virtualenv, monorepo, python-poetry

I have a monorepo with multiple projects in it. Each of them has its own dependencies. I'm working daily on each of these projects and I have to handle each of them in a new PyCharm window and activate the related virtual environment (I'm using `poetry` by the way), which is very cumbersome.

I think there must be a way to manage all the projects and their virtual environments through only one window. This is possible in a JavaScript monorepo with Webstorm for instance. Is there any best practice or rule about this problem?

Comment: When you open a project, while having another project open, pycharm will ask you, what it should do. Select `Atach` and the project will be append to the already opened one. It will have it's own venv.

Comment: I've never considered this option, gonna try this thanks :)